# Make editText hint italic?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, hint

How do you do this in xml, can you?

I see this in a  related question for the java code to do it, check length is 0 and:

```
EditText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<small><i>" + "Text Hint Here" + "</i></small>"));
```

But can you just do it from xml?

**EDIT:**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/term_entry"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrllyout"
        android:imeOptions="actionNone|flagNoExtractUi"
        android:inputType="text|textImeMultiLine"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Enter Command"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColorHint="#30AAAAAA"
        />
```

Comment: yes, you can do it from xml, setting `android:textstyle="italic"`

Answer (score 0):

try like this in XML

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:hint="hint" 
    android:textStyle="italic" > 
</EditText>
```

to make **hint** use `android:hint="hint"` and for making **italic** word use like this `android:textStyle="italic"`

**updated:**

here is the XML try this, I have tested in my notebook works fine.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/term_entry"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrllyout"
    android:hint="Enter Command"
    android:imeOptions="actionNone|flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="text|textImeMultiLine"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this and it did nothing, no affect at all. I will show you my code. I'll edit it in up above

Comment: Still not italic, with the same code inside a relative layout. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Better use java code.use  `Typeface`. Put your font file in assest folder. And then write below code.

```
italic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Your font file"); 
editText.setTypeface(italic);
```

Comment: Why better? If you set it in code the typeface may get setted double. Do things from XML is mostly the better and cleaner solution.

Comment: yes i prefer to do it from xml but there doesn't seem to be a command?