# Italic hint text, only works on some devices

Tags: android

I have an editText with the following code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/term_entry"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrllyout"
    android:hint="Enter Command"
    android:imeOptions="actionNone|flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="text|textImeMultiLine"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHint="#80AAAAAA"
    android:textStyle="italic" 
/>
```

I am developing on a tablet running 4.0.4, the Samsung Galaxy Tab™ 2 7.0, and the hint text is not italic.

However if I install the app on this tablet running 4.0.4 it does display as italic, why is this? http://www.focalprice.com/CE0127X/MD708_70_Capacitive_5point_TFT_Touch_Screen_Android_403_Tablet_PC.html?#.UPmbg6F9G6Q?Currency=EUR

Ok I made it italic by doing this, Inside strings.xml:

```
 <string name="Enter_Command"><i>Enter Command</i></string>
```

In .xml file

```
 <EditText android:hint="@string/Enter_Command" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `textStyle` modifies the edited text, not the hint text. the hint text style is device specific.

Therefore, this line of XML does not affect the hint:

```
android:textStyle="italic"
```

Comment: Ah I see, I had thought there was no way I could make the hint italic, so there is not? I was just surprised then on the other tablet when i installed the app and still had this old line of code in. Coincidence then. The edited text is also not in italic on the samsung however. The line appears to do nothing.

Comment: I was wondering because of this question I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648959/make-edittext-hint-italic

Comment: The post you reference in the link above is not correct about the 'textStyle', but it has an excellent idea for how to italicize the hint text programmatically: "EditText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<small><i>" + "Text Hint Here" + "</i></small>"));"

Comment: Thanks yes, that's good. I like to know both ways, so my edited post shows away in the xml and I have both now. :)